# Show content only on front page?

Tags: pagination, homepage

I want to add some content (slider) only on the home page. I don't want it to apear on the other pages. I am trying following:

```
<?php if(is_home()) { ?>
<div>
...
<div>
} ?>
```

But the content still appears on the second page (in pagination). How can i show some content to homepage only, so that id does not appear on second page?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php if(is_home() && !is_paged()) { ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags

Answer (score 2):

The following lines should speak for themselve:

```
global $paged;

$max_page = (int) $wp_query->max_num_pages;
if ( $max_page > (int) 1 )
    $paged = ! $wp_query->query_vars['paged'] ? (int) 1 : $wp_query->query_vars['paged'];

// If not on the first page, not on the home or static front page and not if paged should (for some) reason be zero
if ( (int) 1 !== $paged && (int) 0 !== $paged && ( ! is_home() || ! is_front_page() ) )
{
    // display stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `<?php if(is_front_page()) { ?>` I believe this is for using with sites that use a static home page.

Answer (score 0):

I always use home.php instead of index.php if I want a completely different home page than the other pages.

I put this code in just before The Loop on home.php:
`<?php query_posts('cat=X&showposts='.get_option('posts_per_page')); ?>` 
where cat=X is the category ID of a category I created and usually call Homepage or Frontpage.

Then on the index page place this code:
`<?php query_posts($query_string . '&cat=-X'); ?>` 
before the loop where &cat=-X is the same ID of your Homepage category. Notice the minus sign.

Now just pick the Homepage or Frontpage category for the posts you want only on the home page.